# Direct sum of HIlbert spaces isomorphic to...

Tags: hilbert-spaces, direct-sum, vector-space-isomorphism

I need to clear my mind in order to solve some excersices:
I need to proof that $\mathbb{C}^{n_1} \oplus \mathbb{C}^{n_2} \cong \mathbb{C}^{n_1+n_2}$ where $\mathbb{C}^{n_1}$ and $\mathbb{C}^{n_1}$ are Hilbert spaces, but I'm not so clear about what I need to prove. Could you please help me by giving me some tips?

Comment: You need the definition of direct sum and of isomorphism for start, then you need to exhibit a specific isomorphism between the given spaces (it's just like $((a_1,\dots, a_{n_1}),\, (b_1,\dots,b_{n_2}))\mapsto (a_1,\dots,a_{n_1},\,b_1,\dots,b_{n_2})$).

Comment: I've already got this, but what's next? I mean, what about the norms and the inner product? What do I need to do in this sense?

Comment: How is the inner product defined on the direct sum?

Comment: it is not said on the excersice but I imagine it is as usual $<(x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)>=<x_1,y_1>+<x_2,y_2>$ where $x_1,y_1 \in \mathbb{C}^n_1$ and $x_2,y_2 \in \mathbb{C}^n_2$

Comment: Then isn't it straightforward that the above mapping preserves this?

Comment: yes, it is obvious, but my question is: what should I do to ensure they are isomorphic?

For example, in linear algebra I need to give the function, and then test injectivity and surjectivity. I mean, I have doubts about concepts, not procedures, I don't know if you can understand me...

Comment: Ah, yes, I see. Your question could have been then more specific into this direction... An isomorphism $\varphi$ of Hilbert spaces is a linear isomorphism (so, linear, injective and surjective) which also preserves the inner product (satisfying $\langle \varphi(a),\varphi(b)\rangle =\langle a,b\rangle$). That's all.

Comment: thanks, that´s what I was looking for